# Is $xy\leq z$ or $xy\geq z$ quasi convex or quasi concave in some infinite subset of $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}^3$?

Tags: convex-analysis

Is $xy\leq z$ or $xy\geq z$ quasi convex in some infinite subset with positive measure of $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}^3$?

If not is it quasi-concave in some infinite subset with positive measure of $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}^3$?

Comment: What is your definition of "quasi convex"?

Comment: @gerw The standard one in usage.

Comment: Please give the definition. The standard definition is for a function, but in my opinion "$xy \le z$ or $xy \ge z$" is not a function.

Comment: Both are neither in whole of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: If you do not answer my request properly, I cannot help you...

Comment: @gerw $x^2\leq y$ is a convex constraint on whole of $\mathbb R^2$ and thus convex on any convex subset of $\mathbb R^2$. We cannot say same about $xy\leq z$ or $xy\geq z$ as these are not convex constraints on whole of $\mathbb R^3$. By convex constraint inequality we mean the inequality defines a convex region in $\mathbb R^n$ and the answer to my problem is positive in a region of $0$ measure (low dimensional subsets for example $y=1$).